# HLSL float bitfield

Tags: shaders, hlsl, floating-point

In HLSL I want to store a bitfield for each color in a texture. Specifically spanning 3 floats (RGB, not alpha).

Since each float has to be between 0 and 1 I can only use the significand/mantissa of each float (last 23 bits) which should give me 23*3 = 69 values for my bitfield.

How can I set and get specific bits? (without bitwise operators, obviously, since these are floats)

Remember to take floating point precision errors into consideration.

Comment: Why are you using Shader Model 2.0? Are you targeting Direct3D 11 9.x Feature Levels?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that exactly. I'm making a 2D game, so I just figured the lower Shader Model the better because I can target older hardware and 2.0 is good enough for all my other shaders. I guess I could use 3.0 without any losses nowadays, but even if this was for 4.0 where bitwise operators for integers are supported, what difference would it make? You can set and get bits for integers with arithmetic operators as well, right?

Comment: If you look at the [Steam hardware survey](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/videocard/) you capture like 95% of the market with ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`` (Shader Model 2.0); and 99% with ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0`` (Shader Model 4.0). Just don't worry about it and focusing on making your game fun and cool. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/)

Comment: D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 is shader model 5.0 and I capture less of the market by using 2.0 than 4.0? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: But yes I get your point. By using 3.0 instead of 2.0 I would only lose 0.01% of the people on Steam. Even if I used 1.0 I would only gain 0.94% and by using 4.0 instead of 1.0 I would only lose a total of 1.05% of the people on Steam. So using anything below 4.0 with the argument that it would expand the market is completely redundant. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with floats? A pair of fixed-point RGBA 8bpc textures would get you 64 bits to play with, out of 64 bits per pixel stored, and you'd have a much easier time of it. Using an RGB 32 bit float texture you'd burn 96 bits per pixel but only get easy access to 69 of those bits as payload. If you're storing bitwise data that's not suitable to interpolate anyway, then textures might not even be the best storage method, and other types of buffers might let you handle this without juggling the fiction that these bits are colour data. Can you explain why floats are needed here?

Comment: Well, I guess I don't. If there is a performant way to use a pixel shader to write to a 2D array of uints or something of size texture width*texture height that can then be accessed by another pixel shader then that would be better.

Comment: Actually, since you can't use non-constant arrays in shaders I don't see what else than textures I could use. I guess I could use a texture with a different format, but I've never done that before or seen a pixel shader that returned anything else than float4. I also need to store the alpha value which is between 0 and 1. What texture format would allow me to have the largest bitfield and store the alpha value? What would the pixel shader return type be and how would you sample the texture?

Comment: BTW, I'm using MonoGame, so these are the supported formats: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SurfaceFormat.cs RGBA64 seems to be the best I can get, giving me 16*3 = 48 bits, so I think I'll stick with the color format as it gives me the most amount of bits (69) and easy storage of alpha channel (0-1). Unless you can elaborate on what you mean by buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The trick is you can clamp an integer between 0 and 1 by dividing 1 by it, to "unpack" it you divide 1 by the result and the way that floats work I think you could technically use all 32 bits in the 0-1 range. The problem is precision.
If you're using Shader Model 4.0 you can use bitwise operators for the integer bitfield, otherwise, you can do this:

Read a bit from float:

```
fmod(1.0 / num, pow(2, bit + 1)) >= pow(2, bit);
```

Set bit that is 0 to 1 (when I set a bit to 1 I know it's 0 if that's not the case you could always read the bit to check first):

```
num = 1.0 / (round(1.0 / num) + pow(2, bit))
```

You can store a bitfield of 23 bits in a float with this method, but beyond 23 bits the precision is too bad for the round function to handle.

For RGB this gives you a bit field of 23*3 = 69 bits. You can access RGB component by integer division:

```
rgba[bit / 23]
```

Get bit in RGB component with modulus:

```
fmod(bit, 23)
```